# Output lists with new line for each record element

Tags: output-formatting

When Mathematica outputs nested lists, it just gloms one record right after the next record and it wraps around in the space available, for example:

```
In[10]:= FactorInteger[FromDigits["1000000000000101",Range[2,10]]]
Out[10]= {{{13,1},{2521,1}},{{11,1},{251,1},{5197,1}},{{3,2},{229,1},{520981,1}},{{4751,1},{6423401,1}},{{173,1},{281,1},{2677,1},{3613,1}},{{3,1},{61,2},{425294411,1}},{{53,1},{157,1},{1697,1},{2491681,1}},{{109,1},{75403,1},{25050853,1}},{{3,1},{47,1},{157,1},{1021,1},{44244113,1}}}
```

What would be more convenient would be to be able to see each record on its own line. So, for example, in the example above there are 9 records, one for each of the input values 2-10. I can kind of see the separation between them by looking for the double "}}", but it is stressful. Is there an easy way to have a line break after each record, so it is more obvious where one record ends and the next begins?

Comment: Maybe `TableForm` ?

Comment: Look up  `Column`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments I developed the following answer. Not completely simple, but not too onerous to do:

```
In[38]:= TableForm[Part[FactorInteger[FromDigits["1000000000000101",Range[2,10]]],All,All,1]]
Out[38]//TableForm= 
13    2521          
11    251      5197     
3     229      520981       
4751  6423401           
173   281      2677       3613  
3     61       425294411        
53    157      1697       2491681   
109   75403    25050853     
3     47       157        1021      44244113
```

So, for each of the 9 cases there is a row, and it is clear which values belong in which row.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
Print[#] & /@ Flatten[
  FactorInteger[FromDigits["1000000000000101", Range[2, 10]]], 1];
```